# When using EFL for an embedded UI, should we use Elementary or Edje?

Tags: linux, user-interface, tizen, efl

We are starting with an embedded development using the Enlightenment Foundation Libraries. We are developing a "full" screen application, so a window manager is not required and our Linux system will eventually run Tizen OS.

The question is, EFL provides Elementary and Edje.

Should we use Elementary widgets or Edje scripts?

Can you use Elementary widgets in Edje scripts? I have heard mention of this but have not seen any documentation or examples.

Answer (score 1):

EFL provides a no. of libraries for different GUI tasks. Generally based on requirements you need to opt for a particular lib. elementary provides set of widgets already created for user. So go for it if you can reuse. But do implement it with edje as edje is helpful for defining layouts and will help you when you need to scale up or down your graphics app. you can refer following link for detail api documentation:

http://web.enlightenment.org/p.php?p=docs&l=en

Answer (score 1):

Use elementary first. You can do most of things and it supports a lot of features such as theme, focus, container, access, auto deletion, scale, mirror, translate, orientation set and etc.

If you really want to use edje(edc script) then use elm_layout and set edj file.

Thanks.